# JavaFX ListView multiple selection not working after applying CSS styling

Tags: css, listview, javafx-8

When I try to style JavaFX ListView control using CSS, it disables the Multiple selection mode set up using below piece of code in the `initialize` method in `Controller` class.

```
listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

Funny thing is, when I remove the CSS completely, it just works fine. Any idea what exactly is going on here.

**ListView in CSS:**

```
.listView .list-cell:filled:selected:focused, .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#328BDB 0%, #207BCF 25%, #1973C9 75%, #0A65BF 100%);
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.listView .list-cell { 
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.listView .list-cell:odd { 
    -fx-background-color: #EFEFF0;
}

.listView .list-cell:even { 
    -fx-background-color: #E4E5E6;
}

.listView .list-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        #A6A6A6 20%,
        #A0A0A0 40%,
        #9D9D9D 60%,
        #A0A0A0 80%,
        #A3A3A3 100%
        );
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.listView {
    -fx-background-radius: 4;
    -fx-border-radius: 4;
    -fx-padding: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just on the first line of your css, since the `listView` styleclass is missing:

Wrong:

```
.listView .list-cell:filled:selected:focused, 
.list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#328BDB 0%, #207BCF 25%, #1973C9 75%, #0A65BF 100%);
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Correct:

```
.listView .list-cell:filled:selected:focused, 
.listView .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#328BDB 0%, #207BCF 25%, #1973C9 75%, #0A65BF 100%);
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, wow didn't realize that.
Just one of those days when you look for something bigger but apparently that's just a pretty simple thing right in front of your eyes. Thanks.